# React native avoid truncating the text in a Picker

Tags: android, react-native, truncate, picker

I have time trying to get the full text displayed in a picker, without having positive results.

I tried the example published in [NativeBase](https://github.com/GeekyAnts/NativeBase/issues/959) but it did not work for me, it only seems to work in IOS.

How I can avoid to truncate text in a Picker?

output: [Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eTpPM.jpg)

Example code:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { Picker } from 'react-native';

class Test extends Component {
render() {
    return (
        <Picker
            placeholder="select"
            mode="dropdown"
            selectedValue={1}
        >

            <Picker.Item
                label={"Long long long long long text text text text text text text text"}
                value={1}
            />
            <Picker.Item
                label={"Long long long long long text text text text text text text text"}
                value={2}
            />
            <Picker.Item
                label={"Long long long long long text text text text text text text text"}
                value={3}
            />
            <Picker.Item
                label={"Long long long long long text text text text text text text text"}
                value={4}
            />
        </Picker>
    );
}
}
```

Comment: Having the same problem... Anybody ?

Comment: me too facing same issue

Comment: Still the issue.